# Need a specific regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create the following regex:

```
* [ * , * ] *
```

where `*` can be any text of any size
I have tried the following:

```
/[*.,.*]/
```

but it is not it
(if it matters I will need it for JavaScript)

Examples for the correct text:

- test[1,2]
- test[3,test2]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give some examples of correct strings ?

Comment: Try `/(.*)\[(.*),(.*)\](.*)/`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]
^----^ anything but [
      ^^ - [
        ^----^ - anything but ]
              ^^ - ]
```

Optionally you can wrap your whole regex in `^` and `$` to match whole string only.

Example:

```
> /^[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]$/.test("test[1,2]")
true
> /^[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]$/.test("test[1,test2]")
true
> /^[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]$/.test("test_wrong")
false
> /^[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]$/.test("test[wrong")
false
```

Comment: You could also use lazy stars: `.*?` instead of negated classes.

Comment: @thg435, yes. I guess it's a matter of choice in this case. I just like explicit negate more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[[^,]*,[^]]*\]/
 --               opening bracket
   ----           non-comma
       -             any number of them
        -         comma
         ----     non-closing-bracket
             -       any number of them
              --  closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^.*\[.*,.*\].*$/

// e.g:
"my [awesome, string] of text".match(/^.*\[.*,.*\].*$/)
```

Comment: That's good, but . will match white space as well, which I assume is not desirable given the example text provided.

Comment: Will fail when there are two expected matches, due to greediness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
/\S+\[\S+,\S+\]/
```

Do you want grouped results as well?

As pointed out, \S will match any non-whitespace character, including ,  So this may be better but is harder to read.

```
/([\w\d]+\[[\w\d]+,[\w\d]+\])/g
```

I have added brackets so that you can use it with the match method for obtaining a list of all matching occurrences.

Comment: no i will only need to get one string out of this regex and not a group of strings, but thanks :)

Comment: If you do something like this: thing.match(re) it will return all the matches.  Using () to group what you are actually interested in will get you all occurrences in a single string, if you trail your regex with the 'g' flag.

Comment: Will also match `a[1,2,3]`.

Comment: True, so use: /([\w\d]+\[[\w\d]+,[\w\d]+\])/g  Note, I have added grouping to this one to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regexp:

`/.*\[.*,.*\].*/`

Comment: Will fail when there are two expected matches, due to greediness.

Comment: If you only want to match for presence, it might be sufficient. If you want to count, or capture, or substitute, it will go horribly wrong. Also, it will match `test[1,2,3,4]` as well, against spec.

Comment: Well, topic started has specified `when * can be any text of any size`. So to check for presence this is perfectly valid